# Saving changes after editing profile not showing

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

So i'm working on this the profile page(which is a fragment) of my app and i'm trying to edit everything(for now) on the profile page. Editing the text works fine, the problem arises when i try to save it. It just shows me a Toast message saying changes saved but I don't see the changes being applied on the profile page. Also after clicking on the save changes, the page does not go back to text view until i navigate away to another page and when i come back, it just displays the unedited profile. Any idea on how to fix this??

```
package com.example.datingapp;

import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;


public class ProfileFragment extends Fragment {
    TextView profileName, profileEmail, profileUsername, profilePassword;
    TextView titleName, titleUsername;
    Button editButton;
    private boolean isEditing = false;
    private ProfileViewModel profileViewModel;
    private DatabaseReference reference;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        profileViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).get(ProfileViewModel.class);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, container, false);
        profileViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).get(ProfileViewModel.class);
        reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

        profileName = view.findViewById(R.id.profileName);
        profileEmail = view.findViewById(R.id.profileEmail);
        profileUsername = view.findViewById(R.id.profileUsername);
        profilePassword = view.findViewById(R.id.profilePassword);
        titleName = view.findViewById(R.id.titleName);
        titleUsername = view.findViewById(R.id.titleUsername);
        editButton = view.findViewById(R.id.editButton);

        Bundle args = getArguments();
        if (args != null) {
            String nameUser = args.getString("name");
            String emailUser = args.getString("email");
            String usernameUser = args.getString("username");
            String passwordUser = args.getString("password");

            profileViewModel.setName(nameUser);
            profileViewModel.setEmail(emailUser);
            profileViewModel.setUsername(usernameUser);
            profileViewModel.setPassword(passwordUser);

            if (nameUser != null && emailUser != null && usernameUser != null && passwordUser != null) {
                titleName.setText(profileViewModel.getName());
                titleUsername.setText(profileViewModel.getUsername());
                profileName.setText(profileViewModel.getName());
                profileEmail.setText(profileViewModel.getEmail());
                profileUsername.setText(profileViewModel.getUsername());
                profilePassword.setText(profileViewModel.getPassword());
            }
        }
        editButton.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            if (!isEditing) {
                enableEditing();
                isEditing = true;
                editButton.setText("Save Profile");
            } else {
                saveChanges();
                isEditing = false;
                editButton.setText("Edit Profile");
            }
        });
        return view;
    }

    private void enableEditing() {
        // Enable editing for profile fields
        profileName.setEnabled(true);
        profileEmail.setEnabled(true);
        profileUsername.setEnabled(true);
        profilePassword.setEnabled(true);

        // Change TextViews to EditTexts for profile fields
        convertToEditText(profileName);
        convertToEditText(profileEmail);
        convertToEditText(profileUsername);
        convertToEditText(profilePassword);
    }

    private void saveChanges() {
        // Disable editing for profile fields
        profileName.setEnabled(false);
        profileEmail.setEnabled(false);
        profileUsername.setEnabled(false);
        profilePassword.setEnabled(false);

        // Retrieve and update data from EditText fields to ViewModel or any other storage mechanism
        profileViewModel.setName(profileName.getText().toString());
        profileViewModel.setEmail(profileEmail.getText().toString());
        profileViewModel.setUsername(profileUsername.getText().toString());
        profileViewModel.setPassword(profilePassword.getText().toString());

        // Update TextViews with new data from ViewModel
        profileName.setText(profileViewModel.getName());
        profileEmail.setText(profileViewModel.getEmail());
        profileUsername.setText(profileViewModel.getUsername());
        profilePassword.setText(profileViewModel.getPassword());

        profileName.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        profileEmail.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        profileUsername.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        profilePassword.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Changes Saved!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        // You can also perform any saving logic here, like updating a database
    }

    // Helper method to convert TextView to EditText
    private void convertToEditText(TextView textView) {
        textView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        EditText editText = new EditText(requireContext());
        editText.setLayoutParams(textView.getLayoutParams());
        editText.setText(textView.getText());
        editText.setId(textView.getId());
        editText.setHint(textView.getHint());

        ViewGroup parentLayout = (ViewGroup) textView.getParent();
        int index = parentLayout.indexOfChild(textView);
        parentLayout.removeView(textView);
        parentLayout.addView(editText, index);
    }
}
```

I've tried making the textview visible after i was done editing but it's not fixing it. I've attached my code for reference. Since i'm using a fragment i'm also using a ViewModel in my mainActivity to display the profile page permanently without deleting the data but somehow for the editing it's not working. I'll attach my MainActivity.java below

```
{

    private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    TextView profileName, profileEmail, profileUsername, profilePassword;
    TextView titleName, titleUsername;
    private ProfileViewModel profileViewModel;
    ActivityMainBinding binding;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // bottom navigation
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());

        replaceFragments(new HomeFragment());
        binding.bottomNavigationView.setBackground(null);

        binding.bottomNavigationView.setOnItemSelectedListener(item ->{
            if (item.getItemId() == R.id.home) {
            replaceFragments(new HomeFragment());
        } else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.shorts) {
            replaceFragments(new ShortsFragment());
        } else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.subscriptions) {
            replaceFragments(new SubscriptionFragment());
        } else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.profile) {
            replaceFragments(new ProfileFragment());
        }
            return true;
        });

        // navigation drawer
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        Objects.requireNonNull(getSupportActionBar()).setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

        drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.open_nav, R.string.close_nav);

        drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        if(savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new HomeFragment()).commit();
            navigationView.setCheckedItem(R.id.nav_home);
        }

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.fragment_container, new HomeFragment())
                    .commit();
            navigationView.setCheckedItem(R.id.nav_home);
        }

        BottomNavigationItemView profileButton = findViewById(R.id.profile); // Assuming you have a button in your layout for profile navigation
        profileButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Call the function to navigate to the ProfileFragment with user data
                navigateToProfileFragmentWithData();
            }
        });
    }

    // navigation drawer
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.nav_home) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new HomeFragment()).commit();
        } else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.nav_settings) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new SettingsFragment()).commit();
        } else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.nav_share) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new ShareFragment()).commit();
        } else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.nav_about) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new InfoFragment()).commit();
        } else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.nav_logout) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Logout!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.profile) {
            // When profile is clicked, navigate to ProfileFragment with user data
            navigateToProfileFragmentWithData();
        }
        drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    // navigation bottom
    private void replaceFragments(Fragment fragment){
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }

    public void navigateToProfileFragmentWithData() {
        // Data to be passed to the ProfileFragment
        // Check if Intent contains user data
        profileViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(ProfileViewModel.class);

        // Check if Intent contains user data
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        if (intent != null) {
            String nameUser = intent.getStringExtra("name");
            String emailUser = intent.getStringExtra("email");
            String usernameUser = intent.getStringExtra("username");
            String passwordUser = intent.getStringExtra("password");

                profileViewModel.setName(nameUser);
                profileViewModel.setEmail(emailUser);
                profileViewModel.setUsername(usernameUser);
                profileViewModel.setPassword(passwordUser);

                Bundle args = new Bundle();
                args.putString("name", nameUser);
                args.putString("email", emailUser);
                args.putString("username", usernameUser);
                args.putString("password", passwordUser);


                ProfileFragment profileFragment = new ProfileFragment();
                profileFragment.setArguments(args);

                // Perform a fragment transaction to display ProfileFragment
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.fragment_container, profileFragment)
                        .addToBackStack(null) // If needed to handle back navigation
                        .commit();
            }
    }
}
```